# Java 8 Functional interface assignment context

Tags: java, java-8

Question is regarding assignment context of functional interface-

```
Predicate<String> p = String::isEmpty;
```

Works fine where the `isEmpty` method declaration in String class is - `public boolean isEmpty(){}`.

If I try to declare same in custom class like -

```
class Test{
   public boolean isEmpty(){
       ...
   }
}
```

And make same assignment -

```
Predicate<String> p = Test::isEmpty;
```

It would be compilation error -

> The type Test does not define isEmpty(String) that is applicable
>   here

And `Predicate<T>` represents a predicate (boolean-valued function) of one argument and  functional method is `boolean test(T t){}`.

Any explanation? And am I missing anything?

Comment: Pretty simple: a class is not an interface, so it cannot be a functional interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should have:

```
Predicate<Test> p = Test::isEmpty;
```

and not

```
Predicate<String> p = Test::isEmpty;
```

There is no String in

```
class Test {
    public boolean isEmpty(){
           ...
    }
}
```

so why should there be `Predicate<String>` ?

See the [tutorial of method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). What you have here is the 3rd case "Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type".

Having

```
Predicate<String> p = String::isEmpty();
String s = "";
```

Calling `p.test(s);` is the same as callign `s.isEmpty();` so that's why you cannot give as argument a `String` to call a method from `Test`.

It would have been possible to have a common `Predicate` if both `String` and `Test` would implement an interface `Empty` with the method `boolean isEmpty()` and then to have `Predicate<Empty>`. Then both `p.test(string)` and `p.test(test)` would work; otherwise it won't, Java has strong typing and does not support duck typing.

Answer (score 4):

The method reference can be used in a few ways. It can capture an instance on which to be invoked. It can refer to a method that should be invoked on the parameter provided by the functional interface (your first example). It can also be used as an invocation target where the parameter in the functional interface is passed as an argument to an invocation of the method referenced (your second example).

The `Predicate` accepts a parameter of whatever your generic type argument is. Your provided method reference must be able to do something with it.

Comment: can you tell me the compilation logic behind the functional interface assignment.

Comment: @sub It's in the JLS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1). See the second point.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to @m3th0dman's answer.

You do have a way to define a `Predicate<String>` with a method reference of your `Test` class. The way to do it is by defining the `isEmpty` method to be static and have a `String` argument.

```
public class Test
{

  public static boolean isEmpty (String s)
  {
    return s.length() == 0;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      Predicate<String> p = Test::isEmpty;
      System.out.println(p.test("ff"));
      System.out.println(p.test(""));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used `Predicate<String>` then only the method reference of `String` is acceptable.
To give method reference of `Test` class you will need `Predicate<Test>`
Therefore the code should be :

```
Predicate<Test> p = Test::isEmpty;
```

instead of

```
Predicate<String> p = Test::isEmpty;
```

To make my point more clear consider the following code : -

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Predicate<String> p;
    p = String::isEmpty;
    Predicate<Test> q;
    q = Test::isEmpty;
}

interface Predicate<T>{
    public boolean test(T t);
}

class Test{
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return true;
    }
}
```