# Why does Function<Interface, R> not accept a method reference from a subclass?

Tags: java, function, generics

Let's say I have an interface `Animal` with the method `String getRace()` and a subclass `Dog`. I keep some animals in a `List<Animal>`.

Now if I wanted to sort that list and passed a `Function<Animal, String>` into the method to use it together with `Comparator.comparing(...)` that would work fine. However, if I reference a function from `Dog` to pass as an argument, the compiler throws the following error:

> The type Zoo.Dog does not define getRace(Zoo.Animal) that is applicable here.

even though it's a subclass of `Animal` and does define that function.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Zoo {

    public interface Animal {

        public String getRace();

    }

    public class Dog implements Animal {

        public String getRace() {
            return "Some race";
        }

    }

    private List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(new Animal[] {});

    public void sort(Function<Animal, String> function) {
        animals = animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(function)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();

        // Error: "The type Zoo.Dog does not define getRace(Zoo.Animal) that is applicable here"
        zoo.sort(Dog::getRace);
    }

}
```

Why is that?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197066/java-8-functional-interface-assignment-context), but in that example the classes are in no relation to each other.

Comment: because the `List` is if `Animal` type but not `Dog` type

Comment: @Deadpool Right, I kind of expected something like that. I was confused since `Dog` can do everything an `Animal` could do.

Comment: In short: not every `Animal` is a `Dog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
    zoo.sort(Animal::getRace);
}
```

The reason is simple:

To sort a List of `Animal` using a `Comperator`, it needs to be a `Comperator<Animal>`. This means the function you pass into `Comperator.comparing` needs to
   be of a `Function<? super Animal,? extends Comperable>`. This is not
   true for `Function<Dog, String>`, however it is true for
   `Function<Animal, String>` and `Function<Object, String>`.

You correctly define your `.sort()` to take a `Function<Animal, String>` - but you pass in a member function of `Dog` - this is essentialla a Function `Dog -> String`, or `Function<Dog,String>` in functional interfaces.

---

In less technical terms: yes, a `Dog`can do everything an `Animal` can. The way around however is not true - a `Dog` can have a function that not all animals have. Therefore, it's not valid to use a `Function<Dog,?>` in place of a `Function<Animal,?>` - but it would be ok the way around.

Comment: Right, makes sense. I haven't really worked with method references before, that's why I was confused.

Comment: @Shred It's more an issue with generics. Generic types in Java, including generic Interfaces, are only enforced by the compiler. All type information is erased at runtime - this is called "type erasure" if you want to google it. This means you are only allowed tihngs with generics that the compile can ensure - which is why you cannot put a function of `Dog` in place of a funciton of `Animal` here. The compiler just can't ensure that, at runtime, the method signature is still compatible with the one of `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

`Dog::getRace` expects a `Dog` instance, but `animals.stream()` provides `Animal` instances.

What should work, I guess, since `Dog` implements `Animal` and `getRace` is declared in `Animal`:

```
    zoo.sort(Animal::getRace);
```